# facebook login for C# .User's email not be returned

Tags: facebook, .net-3.5, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'myappid', // App ID
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // Additional initialization code here
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                // request, and the time the access token 
                // and signed request each expire
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                // TODO: Handle the access token
                // Do a post to the server to finish the logon
                // This is a form post since we don't want to use AJAX
                var form = document.createElement("form");
                form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
                form.setAttribute("action", 'facebooklogin.aspx');

                var field = document.createElement("input");
                field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                field.setAttribute("name", 'accessToken');
                field.setAttribute("value", accessToken);
                form.appendChild(field);

                document.body.appendChild(form);
                form.submit();

            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                // but has not authenticated your app
            } else {
                // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
            }
        });
    };
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    } (document));
</script>
<div class="fb-login-button"  data-show-faces="false"
    data-width="400" data-max-rows="1">
</div>
```

.cs code

```
        var accessToken = HttpContext.Current.Request["AccessToken"];
        var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
        var me = client.Get("me") as IDictionary<string, object>;
        string firstName = (string)me["first_name"];
        string lastName = me["last_name"].ToString();
        string id = me["id"].ToString();
        string email=me["email"].ToString();
```

Other values can be obtained , except for `email`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not added the permission to access the `email`.

Change your login code to this:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false"
data-width="400" data-max-rows="1" scope="email">
```